# Base repository that all other repositories inherit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I wonder if someone can offer some advice. I have 2 repositories, Repository A and Repository B. Both these repositories currently have a method which is used to setup network credentials to connect to a web service, however each time I call the web service I have to call this method, which is a lot of repetition of code (the network credentials are all the same for each web service). So I'm hoping there is a better way to do this?

What I was thinking is to have a base repository that all the other repositories inherit, which gets instantiated and sets up the network credentials, so that they are available to be used when connecting to the web service. Would this be a good way of doing this or is there a better way?

Just to add I am using Unity for IOC and DI (called in my controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not have a seperate class that handles the calling of the web service, which the repos could use? e.g.

```
public class WebServiceCaller : IWebServiceCaller
{
    private NetworkCredentials credentials { get; set; }

    public WebServiceCaller()
    {
        this.credentials = new NetworkCredentials("Name", "Password");
    }

    // .. Whatever else you need.
}
```

Thus the repos would have this in their constructors:

`public RepoA(IWebServiceCaller caller)`

This way the responsibility of calling the webservice, and authenticating, is taken away from the repos altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track, since you are employing also a DI container, you may easily implement repository pattern and unit of work.

[repository and unit of work patterns](http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/grokking-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns/)